# Angular SSR issue with webpack "Cannot find namespace 'DataTables'"

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, server-side-rendering

I'm using Angular 9 and Datatables, but while running command `npm run build:ssr` getting a error given below:

```
TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'DataTables'.
```

Please let me know if there is any issue, for more detail here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    ....
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
    ....
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    ....
    "angular-datatables": "^10.1.3",
    "datatables.net": "^1.11.2",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.11.2",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.20",
    ...
  },
  "browser": {
    "crypto": false
  }
}
```